# Detect Missing Column Labels in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the dataset outlined here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Balance+Scale

I'm trying create a general function to be able to parse any categorical data following these two rules:

1. Must have a column labeled class containing the class of the object
2. Each row must have the same numbers of columns

Minimal example of the data that I'm working with:

```
Class,LW,LD,RW,RD
B,1,1,1,1
L,1,2,1,1
R,1,2,1,3
R,2,2,4,5
```

This provides 3 unique classes: B, L, R.  It also provides 4 features which pertain to each entry: LW, LD, RW and RD.

The following is a part of my function to handle generic cases, but my issue with it is that I don't know how to check if any column labels are simply missing:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

dataframe = pd.read_csv('Balance_Data.csv')
columns = list(dataframe.columns.values)

if "Class" not in columns:
    sys.exit("'Class' is not a column in the data")

if "Class.1" in columns:
    sys.exit("Cannot specify more than one 'Class' column")

columns.remove("Class")

inputX = dataframe.loc[:, columns].as_matrix()
inputY = dataframe.loc[:, ['Class']].as_matrix()
```

At this point, the correct values are:

```
inputX = array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 2, 1, 1],
                [1, 2, 1, 3],
                [2, 2, 4, 5]])

inputY = array([['B'],
                ['L'],
                ['R'],
                ['R'],
                ['R'],
                ['R']], dtype=object)
```

But if I remove the last column label (RD) and reprocess,

```
Class,LW,LD,RW
B,1,1,1,1
L,1,2,1,1
R,1,2,1,3
R,2,2,4,5
```

I get:

```
inputX = array([[1, 1, 1],
                [2, 1, 1],
                [2, 1, 3],
                [2, 4, 5]])

inputY = array([[1],
                [1],
                [1],
                [2]])
```

This indicates that it reads label values from right to left instead of left to right, which means that if any data is input into this function that doesn't have the right amount of labels, it's not going to work correctly.

How can I check that the dimension of the rows is the same as the number of columns?  (It can be assumed that there are no gaps in the data itself, that each row of data beyond the columns always has the same number of elements in it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pull it out as follows:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv('Balance_Data.csv', index_col=0)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       LW  LD  RW  RD
Class
B       1   1   1   1
L       1   2   1   1
R       1   2   1   3
R       2   2   4   5
```

That way the assertion check can be:

```
if "Class" in df.columns:
    sys.exit("class must be the first and only the column and number of columns must match all rows")
```

and then check that the there are no NaNs in the last column:

```
In [21]: df.iloc[:, -1].notnull().all()
Out[21]: True
```

Note: this happens e.g. with the following (bad) csv:

```
In [31]: !cat bad.csv
A,B,C
1,2
3,4

In [32]: df = pd.read_csv('bad.csv', index_col=0)

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   B   C
A
1  2 NaN
3  4 NaN

In [34]: df.iloc[:, -1].notnull().all()
Out[34]: False
```

I think these are the only two failing cases (but I think the error messages can be made clearer)...

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this answer, but I think it may have the issue backwards. I'm interested in cases where the number of labels < number of features, and I believe this checks if the number of labels > number of features by checking the last column for nan values.  I also don't want to be limited to having the class column be in the first position, I want it to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: @MichaelHackman this checks both I think... but please give it a try on your dataset.

Comment: @MichaelHackman to allow Class anywhere you can do read_csv followed by set_index("Class"). Mainly it's the `df.iloc[:, -1].notnull().all()` that's important.

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correctly, the index_col=n is instructing read_csv to label the rows using column n?